# bash - xmlstarlet -v to $variable

Tags: bash, variables, curl, xmlstarlet

```
wget ${RSS_URL} -O - 2>/dev/null | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item" -v "title" -n -v "link" -n -n
```

That line prints out the title (-v "title) and the url (-v "link") of entries in a rss feed I have.
I want to store the title and url into separate variables ($title and $url for example) so I can use them for curl later.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `xmlstarlet` twice, once for each information you want to get.

To make this efficient, you should download the URL to a local file (so only once `wget`) and then run `xmlstarlet` on that file:

```
title=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item" -v "title" local.xml)
link=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item" -v "link" local.xml)
```

I suggest this approach because it will play well with whitespace in the elements and even new lines.

Note: To optimize the process, you can first filter the XML input to produce a new XML file which just contains the information you want and then run `xmlstarlet` again on that to split it into variables.

Comment: Hmm, actually this does give me a problem. $title now gets all the titles of all entries in the RSS feed, $url also gets all urls of all entries. I'd just like the title & url of the latest entry.

Comment: Fot last entry, modify the xpath expression to "/rss/channel/item[position() = last()]"

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Bash's 'read' built-in to assign multiple variables at once:

```bash
$ read title link <(wget ${RSS_URL} -O - 2>/dev/null | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item" -v "title" -o " " -v "link")
$ echo $title
$ echo $link
```